# binary search on dynamically allocated array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, binary-search

I am working on a program that takes input from redirected file and stores the integers in that file into a dynamic array until -999 is read that is supposed to grow if we try to put more values into it than can be held by its current size.

I am sticking those values into a function that performs binary search that returns the location where found and the amount of comparisons it took to find.

However, when I run it I get all the values in the array including the zero's from all of the empty spaces. Therefore my location variable and comparison variables are thrown off. It is not the function since it works perfect with a hard coded array.

So my question is, is there a way to get rid of that part of the array?
 Thank you

```
int var;
int counter = 0;

int *orgarr;
int size = 10;
orgarr = (int *) malloc (size * sizeof(int) );


int *tempo;
tempo = (int *) malloc (size * 2 * sizeof(int));
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    tempo[i] = orgarr[i];
    free (orgarr);
orgarr = tempo;
size = size * 2;

while (var != -999) {
    scanf("%i", &var);
    if (var != -999){
    orgarr[counter] = var;
    }
    counter++;
}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%i", orgarr[i]);
}
```

Comment: The search invoke is... where? My crystal ball tells me your search parameter limits are `[0..size)`; they should be `[0..counter)`. How about building the array with dynamic resizing *as you read the input*, and only performing a search based on the number of actual *read* entries. That way you kill two problems, your "array is larger than number of entries" problem, and the impending doom of undefined behavior when the array is too **small** for the number of entries.

Comment: `var` is not initialized to any value before `while (var != -999)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right I do have my parameters from 0 to size. 
How would you build it to resize as input is given?

Comment: @chux I was under the impression that I don't need to initialize it at anything because it will keep changing as numbers are being read.

Comment: @Rbutler93 What should the result be of the first time `while (var != -999)` is executed if `var` is not set beforehand?  `var` could have any value: `-999`, some other integer, or a special trap value that throws an exception and stops the program.  True that `var` subsequently changes due to `scanf("%i", &var)`, but that is _after_ the `while` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use realloc to change the size of the array.
If the pointer is set to NULL, realloc will behave the same as malloc on the first allocation of memory.
Consider using "%d". If there were to be any values with leading zeros such as 08, "%i" will try to read them as octal values. In the case of 08, it will fail and 011 will be read as 9. But if you actually have some octal values, you would want to continue to use "%i".
This will reallocate on each input, you could use the `counter` variable to reallocate 10 at a time or double the allocation as needed.
You could also start out by allocating 10,000 and then reallocate to the correct size after reading all the inputs.

```
int var = 0;
int size = 0;
int *tempo = NULL;
int *orgarr = NULL;
while ( ( scanf ( "%d", &var)) == 1) {//invalid input or EOF will end loop
    if ( var != -999) {
        size++;
        tempo = realloc ( orgarr, size * sizeof ( int));
        if ( tempo) {
            orgarr = tempo;
            orgarr[size - 1] = var;
        }
        else {
            //realloc failed
            // return or break but somehow handle the problem
        }
    }
    else {
        break;//read -999
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the temp array to something that won't appear in the redirected file, like for example -1. That way in the loop where you print out the results you can ignore that value.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(orgarr[i] != -1){
       printf("%i", orgarr[i]);
    }
}
```

You are getting the extra zeros being printed out because the array is not being filled up completely. Hope this helps!